# Strange Compiler error with header file on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I starting off a project and starting build some of its structure. I am basing each sensor with a header file and c++ source file under the Arduino's Sensor library in a folder named "Sensors". The file it is complaining about is rather small and uninteresting since it has just been created.

**Error:**

```
In file included from /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/PID/../Sensors/Sensors.h:6,
             from Aircraft.h:5,
             from Aircraft.cpp:1:
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/PID/../Sensors/Compass.h:14: error: multiple types in one declaration
```

**Compass.h**

```
#pragma once

class Compass
{
private:
    double x,y,z;

public:
    void refresh();

    double getX();
    double getY();
    double getZ();
};
```

It complains about `multiple types in one declaration`. But the file seems to be fine. Is there something I am missing? Something I overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing a semi-colon somewhere - likely at one's missing at the closing brace of a class or a struct declaration.

Is there really a semi-colon at the end of `class Compass`?  There is one in your question; I just want to be sure that it's really there in the file (there are a surprising number of SO questions that have code manually typed in rather than copied using the clipboard).

If there is a semi-colon there, check that whatever header is included before `Compass.h` has a semi-colon needed after the last declaration in that file (if needed).

Comment: If it's complaining at the end of `Compass`, it'll be the previous class that's missing the semicolon - probably in Aircraft.h

Comment: There was a semi-colon at the end of Compass. However as @je4d mentioned, there was not a semi-colon mentioned on another file. Just opened up a few other files and found that Gyro.h has a missing semicolon at the end of its class definition. Thanks!